# Deadlock when using netty with Apache Camel

Tags: netty

i have a serious problem. I have a situation where i need to send multiple messages to netty, which are all generated by camel in the same place and then get a response to every single message.

The code is something like that:

```
from("direct:status") 
.split().method("splitMessage", "split").to("direct:device") 

from("direct:device") 
.to("netty:tcp://4533sync=true&decoders=#myDecoders&encoders=#myEncoders") 
.to("direct:send")
```

The splitMessage class generates at least 10 messages, if not more

After the first message is generated, then netty will receive it, it will send reply and forward it. 
And now the second message is generated, it is sent to netty and this is where the problem starts. I will always get an error like that:

```
2011-10-14 10:27:14,326 [ent worker #1-3] ERROR DefaultErrorHandler            - Failed delivery for exchangeId: ID-Stenver-LapTop-60537-1318576334993-0-24. Exhausted after deliver y attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.IllegalStateException: await*() in I/O thread causes a dead lock or sudden performance drop. Use addListener() instead or call await*() from a differ ent thread. 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: await*() in I/O thread causes a dead lock or sudden performance drop. Use addListener() instead or call await*() from a different thread.
```

I have tried to circumvent the problem by delaying the messages, but it doesnt help. I can get past the error by disabling the deadlock, but thats not really a solution.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Do you call ChannelFuture.await(..) within your encoder/decoder ? If not then it may be the camel-netty component which does it. In any case you should never call ChannelFuture.wait(..) from within an I/O-Thread.

Comment: Yeah.  You'd better contact the Camel team or its Netty connector maintainer to report this bug.

Comment: I am not calling ChannelFuture.await()
i am using DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder, StringDecoder, OneToOneDecoder and OneToOneDecoder one more time.
All that the methods do in OneToOneDecoders, is working with Strings
All that Delimiter and String decoders do, is extend that class and call their functionality
Where should i report this to the netty team