# camel-netty causing deadlock when multiple tcp stations are configured in route

Tags: netty, apache-camel

I m getting the following exception when trying to use more than two netty endpoints in a single route.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: await*() in I/O thread causes a dead lock or sudden performance drop. Use addListener() instead or call await*() from a different thread.

Sample route :

```
                            from("netty:tcp://localhost:7000?textline=true") 
                            .bean(DummyProcessor.class) 
                            .to("netty:tcp://localhost:7001?textline=true") 
                            .bean(DummyProcessor.class) 
                            .to("netty:tcp://localhost:7002?textline=true") 
                            .bean(DummyProcessor.class) 
                            .to("netty:tcp://localhost:7003?textline=true") 
                            .bean(DummyProcessor.class) 
                            .to("netty:tcp://localhost:7004?textline=true") 
                            .bean(DummyProcessor.class);
```

camel version : 2.11 
netty 3.6.5

possible duplicate [Deadlock when using netty with Apache Camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138384/deadlock-when-using-netty-with-apache-camel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed by CAMEL-6442: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6442